# Android: AsyncTask won't start

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have Class LocalDatabase in which I comunnicate with SQLiteHelper

```
public class LocalDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

...
   strings etc...
...

public LocalDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
            + KEY_ID + " VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_NAME + " VARCHAR(50))";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

And in MainActivity I have:

```
...
private LocalDatabase locDB;
...

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locDB = new LocalDatabase(this);

    fbLogin();    
}
```

And then in fbLogin() I have function from FB Developers page and in onComplete() method I have this:

```
@Override
public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
    if (user != null) {
         UserName = user.getName();
         UserId = user.getId();

         try {
           if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
           }

           locDB.saveUser(UserId,UserName); //This gave me the exception

         }catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something f***ed up fataly", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }  

    }
}
```

I checked twice my project even with ctrl+f and searched for "new LocalDatabase" but I created it only once...

My LOGCAT:

```
03-17 19:39:45.710: W/System.err(6822): java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.Hennycz.wheresmybuddy/databases/myDatabase
03-17 19:39:45.790: W/System.err(6822):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
03-17 19:39:45.790: W/System.err(6822):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1437)
03-17 19:39:45.790: W/System.err(6822):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
03-17 19:39:45.790: W/System.err(6822):     at com.Hennycz.wheresmybuddy.library.LocalDatabase.saveUser(LocalDatabase.java:51)
03-17 19:39:45.790: W/System.err(6822):     at com.Hennycz.wheresmybuddy.MainActivity$2$1.onCompleted(MainActivity.java:168)
03-17 19:39:45.790: W/System.err(6822):     at com.facebook.Request$1.onCompleted(Request.java:270)
03-17 19:39:45.790: W/System.err(6822):     at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1670)
03-17 19:39:45.790: W/System.err(6822):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-17 19:39:45.790: W/System.err(6822):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-17 19:39:45.790: W/System.err(6822):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-17 19:39:45.790: W/System.err(6822):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4838)
03-17 19:39:45.790: W/System.err(6822):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 19:39:45.800: W/System.err(6822):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-17 19:39:45.800: W/System.err(6822):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
03-17 19:39:45.800: W/System.err(6822):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
03-17 19:39:45.800: W/System.err(6822):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT:

```
public void saveUser(String id, String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    if ( checkUser(id) == 0 ) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, id);
        values.put(KEY_NAME, name);

        db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
    else {
        db.close();
    }
}

public int checkUser(String id) {
    String countQuery = "SELECT id FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN + " WHERE id='"+id+"'";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
    db.close();
    cursor.close();

    return rowCount;
}
```

Do you have any solution please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it. `getReadableDatabase` returns the same **writable** database almost always. So after you perform your query in `checkUser`, you close the **same writable database**, that you further use in `saveUser` method. And because it it definitely closed by now, you get your beautiful exception.

Instead, save your database as a local variable in your helper class, if you intend for further usage and do not close it in `checkUser` and `saveUser`.

You have to manage helper's lifecycle (open and close connection objects, that is) with your `Activity` lifecycle in mind. For example, open helper in `onCreate` and closing in `onDestroy` of your Activity (bear in mind that it is not the most effective approach).

Answer (score 0):

i guess its because you dont close your Objects

try to close

```
locDB = new LocalDatabase(this);
db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
```

at the end of each function

with

```
locDB.close();
db.close();
```

Comment: Hmm, well the error said opening closed object. Maybe it world be not to close the object?

Comment: I have db.close(); in every Function of LocalDatabase

Comment: Edited my post with saveUser method

Answer (score 0):

in `saveUser` you call `checkUser`. In `checkUser`, you call `getReadableDatabase`. This returns you the same instance as previously returned by `getWritableDatabase`.

You then close this database in `checkUser`, and try to still use it in `saveUser`. You then close it in `saveUser`, hence the crash.

Don't close your database unless you know you don't need it.

Alternatively, don't call `getWritableDatabase` in `saveUser` until after you have returned from `checkUser`.